# Reference request: injective homomorphisms between unitary groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, reference-request

Let $U(n)$ be the group of unitary $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$.  Is there a classification of the continuous, injective group homomorphisms $U(m)\to U(n)$?  If so, is there a modern account of the proof?

Comment: You are looking at (faithful) finite dimensional rep. of a compact Lie groups, they are well studied. 
I guess this material is covered at Knapp's book or Fulton-Harris.
(I happen to have Weyl's book in front of me here, but it is more physics-oriented).

I suggest to close the topic as this is not a research level question.

Comment: This is asking about direct sums of irreducible unitary repns of $U(m)$ with total dimension at most $n$. The classification of irreducibles (they are all unitary) of $U(m)$ is by highest weights, and is well-known, well-studied, and visible in many textbooks. The question of the _dimensions_ of the irreducibles for $U(m)$ with $m\ge 3$ is more complicated than the highest-weight classification, but Kostant's weight multiplicity formula tells the dimensions of the weight spaces, giving finer information.

Comment: One can find a table of dimensions of certain irreducible representations of $U(m)$ (or, which is the same, of ${\rm SL}(m)$)and also the classification by highest weights, in the book by Onishchik and Vinberg "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups"

Comment: @Asaf: apologies if the question wasn't appropriate for MO; coming from a different area, I knew that such maps would be well-studied but not under which guise a classification would appear.  I'm happy to vote to close but don't have the reputation at the moment.

Comment: I think that the question is slightly more subtle than it looks, first because the OP asks for injective homomorphisms (= faithful reps), second because what you find in textbooks is $SU(m)$ rather than $U(m)$ ($SU(m)$ corresponds to $SL(m)$, while $U(m)$ corresponds to $GL(m)$, do you agree Mikhail?). 

Comment: A couple of comments: continuous homomorphisms between compact Lie groups are analytic, so may be studied via representation theory as others have indicated. Secondly, the kernel of a non-abelian representation of $U(m), m>1$ will be a subroup of $Z(U(m))\cong U(1)$. Thus, sorting through the faithful representation might be a bit involved, but should reduce to some combinatorics. 